How to replace xml node value in Python, without changing the whole file
Doing my first steps in python I try to parse and update a xml file.
The xml is as follows:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="util/style/aaaa-2-0.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE eu:eu-backbone SYSTEM "../../util/dtd/eu-regional.dtd"[]>
<test dtd-version="3.2" xmlns:test="http://www.ich.org/test" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xlink">
  <mr>
    <leaf  checksum="88ed245997a341a4c7d1e40d614eb14f"   >
      <title>book name</title>
    </leaf>
  </mr>
</test>

I would like to update the value of the checksum.I have written a class with one method:
    @staticmethod
    def replace_checksum_in_index_xml(xml_file_path, checksum):
        logging.debug(f"ReplaceChecksumInIndexXml xml_file_path: {xml_file_path}")
        try:
            from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
            tree = et.parse(xml_file_path)
            tree.find('.//leaf').set("checksum", checksum)
            tree.write(xml_file_path)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error updating checksum in {xml_file_path}: {e}")

I call the method:
    xml_file_path = "index.xml"
    checksum = "aaabbb"
    Hashes.replace_checksum_in_index_xml(xml_file_path, checksum)

The checksum is indeed updated. But also the whole xml structure is changed:
<test dtd-version="3.2">
  <mr>
    <leaf checksum="aaabbb">
      <title>book name</title>
    </leaf>
  </mr>
</test>

How can I update only given node, without changing anything else in given xml file?
UPDATE
Solution provided by LRD_Clan is better than my original one. But it is still changing a bit the structure of xml. Also when I take more complex example I see again part of xml is removed.
More complex example with additional DOCTYPE:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE eu:eu-backbone SYSTEM "../../util/dtd/eu-regional.dtd"[]>
<?xml-stylesheet href="util/style/aaaa-2-0.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>

<test dtd-version="3.2" xmlns:test="http://www.ich.org/test" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xlink">
  <mr>
    <leaf  checksum="88ed245997a341a4c7d1e40d614eb14f"   >
      <title>book name</title>
    </leaf>

  </mr>
</test>

after running updated script the result is:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="util/style/aaaa-2-0.xsl" type="text/xsl"?><test xmlns:test="http://www.ich.org/test" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xlink" dtd-version="3.2">
  <mr>
    <leaf checksum="aaabbb">
      <title>book name</title>
    </leaf>
  </mr>
</test>

I would really like to see only this one xml element being changed and the other part of document to be left intact.
I had similiar solution written in powershell which looks like
 [xml]$xmlContent = Get-Content -Path $xmlFilePath
 $element = $xmlContent.SelectSingleNode("//leaf")
 $element.SetAttribute("checksum, "new text") 
 $xmlContent.Save((Resolve-Path "$xmlFilePath").Path) 

I was hoping I will find something at least same elegant in python.

You can try to call XSLT transformation from Python.

@YitzhakKhabinsky the truth is that I provided only one very simplified scenario out of many which I need to handle. I want to change many different xml files in a different ways (sometimes change the inner text of the node, sometimes different arguments, sometimes remove some elements) so writing xsls for all those scenarious seems like a overhead. But if there will be no other option I will try!:)

Those XSLTs will be mostly one liners. XPath/XSLT/XQuery/XSD are native XML APIs. Everything else is not so native.

Would you be able to provide a working example for this solution?

please add your .dtd sample to the original question. I am trying to compose an XSLT for you, and it needs that .dtd

@facynacja Please vote or/and accept one of the provided answers, if they fulfill your request. Thanks!

The dtd which I have is a big one and has a real data, which I will need to update in order not to share here some sensitive technicalities. I will do that and update my question.

@Hermann12 of course I will upvote all of them since they are valid answers. For the correct answer I have to make test on Monday to see if your answer solves the question, sorry for delay buts its weekend!:)

In addition to LMC’s answer a small modification. You can adjust the parser to keep comments and process instructions:
(Update: add Doctype info to the xml string manually)
from lxml import etree

def replace_checksum(infile, new_value):
    parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_comments=False, remove_pis=False)
    root = etree.parse(infile, parser)

    dtd = root.docinfo.doctype + '\n'

    for elem in root.xpath("//leaf[@checksum]"):
        elem.set("checksum", new_value)
    
    updated_xml = etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding="UTF-8").decode("utf-8")
    
    # add the doctype manually
    i = updated_xml.find('?>\n')
    if len(dtd) > 2:
        updated_doc = updated_xml[:i + len('?>\n')] + dtd + updated_xml[i + len('?>\n'):]
        return updated_doc
    else:
        return updated_xml

if __name__ == "__main__":
    check_sum = "aaabbb"
    outfile = replace_checksum("index.xml", check_sum)
    print(outfile)

Output:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE test SYSTEM "../../util/dtd/eu-regional.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet href="util/style/aaaa-2-0.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<test xmlns:test="http://www.ich.org/test" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xlink" dtd-version="3.2">
  <mr>
    <leaf checksum="aaabbb">
      <title>book name</title>
    </leaf>
  </mr>
</test>

As an ALTERNATIVE, parser doc
The parser option remove_blank_text only removes empty text nodes.
Comments, processing instructions and the doctype are not affected and remain in the parsed document.
from lxml import etree

def replace_checksum(infile, checksum_new, outfile):
    parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
    with open(infile, "rb") as f:
        tree = etree.parse(f, parser)
    
    for elem in tree.xpath("//leaf[@checksum]"):  
        elem.set("checksum", checksum_new)
    
    with open(outfile, "wb") as f:
        tree.write(f, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding="UTF-8", doctype=tree.docinfo.doctype)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    infile = "index.xml"
    outfile = "index_new.xml"
    check_sum = "aaabbb"
    replace_checksum(infile, check_sum, outfile)

File:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="util/style/aaaa-2-0.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE test SYSTEM "../../util/dtd/eu-regional.dtd">
<test xmlns:test="http://www.ich.org/test" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xlink" dtd-version="3.2">
  <mr>
    <leaf checksum="aaabbb">
      <title>book name</title>
    </leaf>
  </mr>
</test>


Is there possibility that this script would not remove the DOCTYPE ?

@fascynacja I have updated my answer and added a solution for the doctype, too.

@fascynacja as an alternative I added another idea.

so far this solution is the best from the proposed. Although it  is still changing the xml  a bit, but maybe those changes will not be problematic for my scenario.

What will be changed? The Whitespaces will be removed. that's clear.

not only, I will create a new question with more difficult example and close this one since my original question did not contain so detailed xml with all this corner cases.

This answer was the closest to the final result and answered my initial question. Just when putting more complex DOCTYPE  and xml element being aa:aa the parser still changes too much. I will create a specific example for this case in another question.

I have created specific question just for the DOCTYPE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79302542/how-to-process-and-update-change-attribute-add-node-etc-xml-file-with-a-doct

I unforntunately Haven't found a Solution using the Library xml.etree that you are using. Instead consider using lxml. Following worked for me:
class Hashes:
    @staticmethod
    def replace_checksum_in_index_xml(xml_file_path, checksum):
        try:
            from lxml import etree
            tree = etree.parse(xml_file_path)
            
            leaf = tree.find('.//leaf')
            if leaf is not None:
                leaf.set("checksum", checksum)

            with open(xml_file_path, 'wb') as file:
                tree.write(file, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8', pretty_print=False)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error updating checksum in {xml_file_path}: {e}")


your solution is better than mine, but still it is changing a bit the xml. For  my question I have simplified the xml example as much as possible, but when I try with more extended version I still have issues. I will update the question with more difficult example

I have created specific question just for the DOCTYPE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79302542/how-to-process-and-update-change-attribute-add-node-etc-xml-file-with-a-doct

It can be done gathering lines between <leaf ...> and </leaf> and parsing them with lxml; printing as is otherwise.
Whitespace after checksum value is lost but there's no way around that.
from lxml import etree

xfile = "/home/lmc/tmp/tmp2.xml"
lines = open(xfile).readlines()

changed = 0
leafstr = ''
for line in lines:
  #print(f"<!-- {line} -->")
  if changed == 0 and 'checksum="88ed245997a341a4c7d1e40d614eb14f"' in line:
    leafstr += line
    changed = 1
  elif changed == 1:
    if '</leaf>' in line:
      leafstr += line
      changed = 0

      ftree = etree.fromstring(f"<root>\n{leafstr}</root>")
      ck = ftree.xpath('//leaf')
      ck[0].set("checksum", "edcrfv")
      # get indentation from last line and add it at the beginning
      leaf_ind = line.split('<',2)[0]
      print(leaf_ind + etree.tostring(ck[0]).decode('utf-8'), end='')
    else:
      leafstr += line
  else:
    print(line, end='')

Result
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE eu:eu-backbone SYSTEM "../../util/dtd/eu-regional.dtd"[]>
<?xml-stylesheet href="util/style/aaaa-2-0.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>

<test dtd-version="3.2" xmlns:test="http://www.ich.org/test" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xlink">
  <mr>
    <leaf checksum="edcrfv">
      <title>book name</title>
    </leaf>

  </mr>
</test>


Here is XSLT based solution. It is using a so called Identity Transform pattern.
To make it flexible, it accepts two parameters:

Attribute name: $attrName.
New value to assign to that attribute: $newValue.

Input XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="util/style/aaaa-2-0.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!--<!DOCTYPE eu:eu-backbone SYSTEM "../../util/dtd/eu-regional.dtd"[]>-->
<test dtd-version="3.2" xmlns:test="http://www.ich.org/test" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xlink">
  <mr>
    <leaf  checksum="88ed245997a341a4c7d1e40d614eb14f"   >
      <title>book name</title>
    </leaf>
  </mr>
</test>

XSLT 1.0
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="utf-8"
                indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="attrName" select="'checksum'"/>
    <xsl:param name="newValue" select="'magicString'"/>

    <!--identity transform-->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*[local-name()=$attrName]">
        <xsl:attribute name="{$attrName}">
             <xsl:value-of select="$newValue"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Output XML
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='no' ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="util/style/aaaa-2-0.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!--<!DOCTYPE eu:eu-backbone SYSTEM "../../util/dtd/eu-regional.dtd"[]>-->
<test xmlns:test="http://www.ich.org/test" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xlink" dtd-version="3.2">
  <mr>
    <leaf checksum="magicString">
      <title>book name</title>
    </leaf>
  </mr>
</test>

Python
import lxml.etree as lx

# PARAMETERS
argDict = {}
argDict["attrName"] = lx.XSLT.strparam("checksum")
argDict["newValue"] = lx.XSLT.strparam("magicString")

# PARSE XML AND XSLT
doc = lx.parse("Input.xml")
style = lx.parse("Process.xslt")
outfile = "Output.xml"

# CONFIGURE AND RUN TRANSFORMER
transformer = lx.XSLT(style)
result = transformer(doc, **argDict)

# OUTPUT TO FILE
with open(outfile, "wb") as f:
    f.write(result)


I tried this solution, unfortunately it failed with exception : "lxml.etree.XSLTParseError: Failed to compile predicate" , For the line :"transformer = lx.XSLT(style)" . I am not sure how to identify what can be wrong and which predicate is missing.

Did you put fully qualified file names for input XML, XSLT, and output XML files?

Files are in the same module and folder where is the script which I am using. Also if I change the name to something wrong like "style = lx.parse("Process_wrong.xslt")" then the compiler complains at this specific line and with a different exception. I have noticed that my IDE shows me also warning at line: "argDict["attrName"] = lx.XSLT.strparam("checksum")" saying: "Parameter 'strval' unfilled ".  btw my python version is : 3.13.1.

I have removed from your script the part where we pass arguments. I have also updated your xsl to use hardcoded values. Then the script compiled but still it had removed the DOCTYPE

I have created specific question just for the DOCTYPE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79302542/how-to-process-and-update-change-attribute-add-node-etc-xml-file-with-a-doct
